# MySQLi using OOP and getting Fatal Error:Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

This is simple stuff and I saw a lot of similar things but nothing that basic. When trying to set up an OOP MySQLi connection using the following code:

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$link) {
  die('Connection Failed: '. $link->error());
}

$sql = "SELECT artist_name FROM artists";

$result = $link->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  printf('Artist: %s<br />', $row['artist_name']);
}

$result->close();

$link->close();
```

I get the following error the $result->fetch_assoc()

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPbook\chapter4\test2.php on line 9
```

I tried some stuff and found out `$link` is indeed an *object* but `$result` is a *boolean*.
This bit of code is taken from a book I'm reading from and wondered if anything changed since the book was written.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to select the database:

`mysqli_select_db($link, 'DATABASE_NAME');`

Answer (score 0):

You have no connection to a database. See `Call to member function query() on a non-object` tells you that the method call `query` can't be executed because `link` doesn't have that method yet available for you. Simply select a database and check that you actually have a real connection to that database.

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_name');

if ($link->connect_error === true) {
  trigger_error('No Connection', E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Continue with your logic ...
```